# Alcatel one touch pop c9 mobile

Tags: superuser

I keep getting "superuser out of date" "install new superuser. Have tried superuser
update fixer.It does nothing. Busy box does nothing. I keep getting "problem installing
Superuser" as well,but it doesn't tell me
what's wrong. Can someone help me, please

Answer (score 0):

You could try **kingo root** win32 application. 
http://www.kingoapp.com/

That should install a modified version of superuser app that might work for your device.

If that works, then never update superuser app, because that update will delete that right version of superuser app.